# Find the values of $a$ such that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(1+e^{ax})}{1+x^2}dx$ converges

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Find the values of $a$ such that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(1+e^{ax})}{1+x^2}dx$ converges

So I've divided into 2 cases, the $a>0$ and $a\leq 0$. For the first one I know how to do it:

**a>0**: The function behaves as $x\to \infty$ like $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(1+e^{ax})}{1+x^2}\sim \int_0^\infty \frac{ax}{1+x^2}\sim \frac{ax}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x}$$ so we can do the limit comparison test as $x\to\infty$:
$$\frac{\frac{\log(1+e^{ax})}{1+x^2}}{\frac{1}{x}}=...=a$$ by L'Hôpitals rule. And as $a>0$ and $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x}$ diverges then ours does as well.

But for $a\leq 0$ I have no clue, any ideas?

Comment: Hint: the logarithm is bounded.

Comment: @metamorphy my book says the numerator (logarithm) is bounded to $\log(2)$, but I can't see how? Since as $x\to \infty$ and $a≤0$ you get $\log(1+e^{ax})\to \log(1+(0))$ which is $\log(1)=0$?

Comment: @Aley20 Yes. That's not a counterpoint, though. You've shown that $\log(1+e^{ax})\to0$, and it's quick to see that this is a lower bound: $0<\log(1+e^{ax})$. The upper bound? Well, $e^{ax}\le e^0=1$ so...

Comment: @FShrike and is there a way to do it with the limit comparison test? I would have never guessed to do the upper bound since it isn't as intuitive to me as the limit comparison test

Comment: Bounding is, when applicable, always the most elementary and (should be) intuitive way to show something converges. In fact, *every convergence test ever* ultimately involves bounding terms or tail sums/integrals

Comment: @FShrike surely true but I'm also interested if there is a limit comparison test way to do it. And thanks in advance